# How to refresh parent Jqgrid from another window.open form which is form posted?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have to refresh a parent grid after window.open (child window) is form posted...

I have tried this code ...

```
 var myWindow = window.open('somefiles');
            myWindow.onbeforeunload = function () {
                $("#pegGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

The problem with this code is not working after the window.open is refreshed or page (form posted) submit action !!

Please help how to solve this issue!!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery('#pegGrid',opener.document).trigger( 'reloadGrid' );

Comment: This is not working since the parent/opener is change once the page gets refreshed or form get posted